Prevent the form from closing
In my application, When I click the "Submit" button on the "MainForm", the "Please Wait" form appears, which shows until the processing is complete. The "Submit" button redirects to "Books.cs". When someone accidentally clicks the Close(X) button on the main form ("MainForm.cs"), the form is closed but the execution is not terminated, the "Please wait" form continues to show and completes the process. It is because the processing is done on a different thread. I want to prevent the user from closing the "MainForm" when the processing is in progress.
My issue is that e.Cancel does not seem to be working. I can still close the mainform. I tried to set the breakpoint on the mainform form closing event, but that breakpoint never hit.
MainForm.cs
private bool isProcessing = false;

private void MainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (isProcessing)
    {
        e.Cancel = true; // Cancel the closing event
    }
    else
    { 
     e.Cancel = false;

    }

public void SetProcessingState(bool processing)
{
    isProcessing = processing;
}

Books.cs

private async Task btnClick()
{
    MainForm mainform = new MainForm();
    
try
    {
      mainForm.SetProcessingState(true);

        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        PleaseWait pleasewait = new PleaseWait();
        pleasewait.Closed += PleaseWait_Closed;
 
        pleasewait.Show();

try{
        // Perform your long-running task asynchronously
        await Task.Run(() => ProcessBookstoreExcel(cts.Token));
}
catch(OperationCanceledException)
{
       cancel = true;
        pleasewait.Close();
       //showmessage
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
        pleasewait.Close();
       //showmessage
}
        pleasewait.Closed -= PleaseWait_Closed;

        pleasewait.Close();

        if(!cancel)
        MessageBox.Show("Processing Complete!");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        cts.Dispose();

        cts = null;
        mainForm.SetProcessingState(false);

    }
}

private void PleaseWait_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e) => cts.Cancel();

private void ProcessBookstoreExcel(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{

try{

    string path = TxtBox.Text;
    ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
    var records = new List<BookRecord>();

    using (var package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(path)))
    {
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
        int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.Rows;

        for (int row = 2; row <= rowCount; row++) // Skip header row
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellation();

            records.Add(new BookRecord
            {
                LineNumber = row,
                ISBN = worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Text,
                Title = worksheet.Cells[row, 2].Text,
                Stock = int.Parse(worksheet.Cells[row, 3].Text),
                Price = decimal.Parse(worksheet.Cells[row, 4].Text),
                PublisherID = int.Parse(worksheet.Cells[row, 5].Text),
                PublisherName = worksheet.Cells[row, 6].Text
            });
        }
    }

    var discrepancies = new List<Discrepancy>();
    var groupedRecords = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, (decimal Price, int Stock)>>();

    foreach (var record in records)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellation();
 
        var publisherKey = record.PublisherID.ToString();
        var isbnKey = record.ISBN;

        if (!groupedRecords.ContainsKey(publisherKey))
        {
            groupedRecords[publisherKey] = new Dictionary<string, (decimal Price, int Stock)>();
        }

        if (!groupedRecords[publisherKey].ContainsKey(isbnKey))
        {
            groupedRecords[publisherKey][isbnKey] = (record.Price, record.Stock);
        }
        else
        {
            var existing = groupedRecords[publisherKey][isbnKey];
            if (existing.Price != record.Price || existing.Stock != record.Stock)
            {
                discrepancies.Add(new Discrepancy
                {
                    LineNumber = record.LineNumber,
                    Publisher = record.PublisherName,
                    Title = record.Title
                });
            }
        }
    }

    WriteDiscrepancies(discrepancies);
}
catch(OperationCanceledException)
{
throw;
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
throw;
}
}

private void WriteDiscrepancies(List<Discrepancy> discrepancies)
{
    try{
    var outputPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath), "discrepancies.xlsx");

    using (var package = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Discrepancies");
        worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "LineNumber";
        worksheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = "Publisher";
        worksheet.Cells[1, 3].Value = "Title";

        for (int i = 0; i < discrepancies.Count; i++)
        {
            worksheet.Cells[i + 2, 1].Value = discrepancies[i].LineNumber;
            worksheet.Cells[i + 2, 2].Value = discrepancies[i].Publisher;
            worksheet.Cells[i + 2, 3].Value = discrepancies[i].Title;
        }

        package.SaveAs(new FileInfo(outputPath));
    }
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}


"but that breakpoint never hit." We see the method but did you connect the method to the event? Either via the designer or in code?

It's also suspicious that you create a new MainForm ...

@Ralf I have connected the method via the designer.

Then we are at @Fildor s remark. Why do you create a new MainForm in your Books class? There is no code that shows that form. You presumably used a Mainform as initial form for your app and here you create presumably another one why you need a additional one that you don't show?

@Ralf for the sake of simplicity. I removed everything and just put Environment.Exit(0) on MainForm.cs form closing event. Put the breakpoint still the breakpoint didnt hit. In my designer i have this.form.closing+= new system.windows.forms.formclosingeventhandler(this.mainform_formclosing);

If the form that is showing the processing process is a Dialog as in ShowDialog then you should not be able to clos ethe main form with the main form's x until the dialog is dismissed.

Problem:
In the "btnClick" method inside "Books.cs" you have created a new instance of the form, but it seems that you do not show it and in fact the displayed form is probably created by "Program.cs".
Therefore, the "SetProcessingState" method sets the field inside a new instance of the form, and in the original form, the value of this field remains false, and as a result, "e.Cancel" is never set.
Solution:
If you have only one main form and one Excel file processing class, you can define "isProcessing" and "SetProcessingState" as static, which solves the problem, or don't create a new instance of the form and use the original instance.
Use one of the codes below:
var openForms = Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().ToList();
var mainForm = (MainForm?)openForms.FirstOrDefault(f => f.GetType().Name == "MainForm");
mainForm?.SetProcessingState(true);

Or (corrected the code written in the question)
private static bool isProcessing = false;
public static void SetProcessingState(bool processing)
{
    isProcessing = processing;
}

